# Hyperbolic motion with non-zero initial velocity

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, velocity

The equations of hyperbolic motion in a single spatial direction with initial velocity of zero are pretty easy to find given a bit of googling, such as in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/75491/12487). And while I'm too rusty at integration to derive them myself, I think I understand the general concepts behind them. However I can't seem to find the same equations for non-zero initial velocity.

Specifically I'm looking for the following equations, but for non-zero initial velocity:
\begin{align}
  v(t) = \frac{ctA}{\sqrt{c^2 + t^2A^2}}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  x(t) = x_0+\frac{c}{A}\left(\sqrt{c^2+t^2A^2}-c\right)
\end{align}
($A$ is proper acceleration, $c$ is the speed of light, $t$ is coordinate time. See the linked answer for derivation of these equations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find them here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_motion_(relativity)

Using $u_0, \gamma_0, X_0, T_0, \tau_0$ as the initial velocity, Lorentz factor, space and time coordinates:

$$\begin{align}u(T) & =\frac{u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T}{c}\right)^{2}}}\quad\\
 & =c\tanh\left\{ \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T}{c}\right)\right\} \\
X(T) & =X_{0}+\frac{c^{2}}{\alpha}\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T}{c}\right)^{2}}-\gamma_{0}\right)\\
 & =X_{0}+\frac{c^{2}}{\alpha}\left\{ \cosh\left[\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T}{c}\right)\right]-\gamma_{0}\right\} \\
c\tau(T) & =c\tau_{0}+\frac{c^{2}}{\alpha}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{c^{2}+\left(u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T\right){}^{2}}+u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T}{\left(c+u_{0}\right)\gamma_{0}}\right)\\
 & =c\tau_{0}+\frac{c^{2}}{\alpha}\left\{ \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{u_{0}\gamma_{0}+\alpha T}{c}\right)-\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{u_{0}}{c}\right)\right\} 
\end{align}$$

as well as

$$\begin{align}u(\tau) & =c\tanh\left\{ \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{u_{0}}{c}\right)+\frac{\alpha\tau}{c}\right\} \\
\\
X(\tau) & =X_{0}+\frac{c^{2}}{\alpha}\left\{ \cosh\left[\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{u_{0}}{c}\right)+\frac{\alpha\tau}{c}\right]-\gamma_{0}\right\} \\
\\
cT(\tau) & =cT_{0}+\frac{c^{2}}{\alpha}\left\{ \sinh\left[\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{u_{0}}{c}\right)+\frac{\alpha\tau}{c}\right]-\frac{u_{0}\gamma_{0}}{c}\right\} 
\end{align}$$